# Android Studio "Editor->Color Scheme" for data class elements

Tags: android-studio

I have tried all the possible options but seem to be missing something.

I'm trying to set 3 different colors here:

data class TestData(
val id: Int,
val type: String,
val content: String
)

So for **val** **id** and **Int** I want to set 3 different colors and I'm not able to get this working. I tried Language Defaults and Kotlin but cannot get it working.

Any suggestions will help please?

Thanks
J

PS: I have Android Studio Bumblebee